# Why qmail is rejecting sending emails with bare LFs characters?

Tags: outlook, qmail

I have a problem with qmail, which is rejecting send emails from 2 email accounts in particular. When I enter through webmail everything works ok but when I use the blessed "MS Outlook" installed on PC's I get an error of the type: "51 See [http://pobox.com/~djb/docs/smtplf.html"](http://pobox.com/%7Edjb/docs/smtplf.html%22) wich means "Bare LFs in SMTP" , which seems to be some LF (line feed) problem.

I have no idea if this can be fixed by configuring the outlook client or running some command in qmail. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: That a Microsoft program in 2022 is sending unix linefeeds `\n` seems unusual, given that Microsoft generally defaults to Internet linefeeds `\r\n`. You could probably patch and recompile qmail to be more accepting.

Comment: I have in the last couple weeks seen updates from both Thunderbird and Outlook causing this problem as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error appears if your client sends incorrectly formatted email messages. All lines in an email messages should end with CR and LF (carrige return and line feed). This message occurs if there are no CR's in the message.
Could you send email successfully through OWA?

Comment: How's everything going now?

Please do not forget to mark helpful reply as answer. Thanks!

Comment: I did tests on the server, which works fine. Finally the client software (outlook ms) was reinstalled and it worked ok, but in depth I don't know what was wrong. I understood perfectly that the client software was sending something wrong (missing CR) to the server, but I don't know why and what caused it in modern clients, just installed.

Comment: what can I say, it's microsoft !

Answer (score 0):

This problem usually arises with badly-configured mail clients or servers.
You can't get mail through to msn.com and thousands of other systems around the Internet. Your mailer is violating 822bis section 2.3, which specifically prohibits all bare LFs.